# sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean give

Tags: php, sql

Tengo el mensaje: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean give

La consulta lo que hace es sacar la diferencia entre dos fechas utilizado SQL, para ello el codigo es el siguiente y no puedo lograr encontrar el error. Gracias:

```
<?php

    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Funciones/Funciones.php';
    require_once 'Functions.php';

    $AMBIENTE = fnAmbiente();

    $FVEN = htmlspecialchars($_GET['FVencimiento']);
    $FECHA_VENCIMIENTO = explode("/","$FVEN");
    krsort($FECHA_VENCIMIENTO);
    $FECHA_VENCIMIENTO = implode("-", $FECHA_VENCIMIENTO);
    $FECHA_VENCIMIENTO = str_replace("-","",$FECHA_VENCIMIENTO);
    //echo $FECHA_VENCIMIENTO;

    $FVAL = htmlspecialchars($_GET['FValuacion']); //FECHA INICIAL SE OBTIENE
    $FECHA_VALUACION = explode("/","FVAL"); //FECHA INICIAL
    krsort($FECHA_VALUACION);
    $FECHA_VALUACION = implode("-", $FECHA_VALUACION);
    $FECHA_VALUACION = str_replace("-","",$FECHA_VALUACION);
    //echo $FECHA_VALUACION;

    $ELEMENTO = htmlspecialchars($_GET['Elemento']);
    // $ELEMENTO = "DIFF";

    $SQL = "SELECT DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(CHAR(8), '$FECHA_VALUACION'), 112), CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(CHAR(8), '$FECHA_VENCIMIENTO'), 112)) DIFF";
    $CONEXION = fnConexionBlotter($AMBIENTE);
    $STMT = sqlsrv_query($CONEXION, $SQL);
    // //$INTERVALO = sqlsrv_fetch_array($RESULTADO);
    $INTERVALO = sqlsrv_fetch_array($STMT);
    //$RESULTADO = $INTERVALO['DIFF'];
    echo $INTERVALO[$ELEMENTO];
    fnDesconexionSQL($CONEXION);

    //RETURN $INTERVALO;

?>
```

Gracias, si ya corregí la sintaxis y lo probe con código duro, ahora lo intento recuperando la información y me dice que el error se encuentra en: $INTERVALO = sqlsrv_fetch_array($STMT);

Comment: Prueba directamente en tu Management Studio la sentencia SQL puede que tengas problemas de sintaxis.

Comment: ¿Qué mensaje de error te da en esa línea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si ya corregiste el problema de sintaxis, para poder imprimir lo que devuelve la consulta utiliza:
En lugar de:  `$INTERVALO = sqlsrv_fetch_array($STMT);`

Utiliza:

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($STMT, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
      echo $row['DIFF'];
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt($STMT);
```